# Get IP address from IPConfig, use later in code, or save

Tags: windows, batch-file, ip

Is it possible to run a code that searches IPConfig for the IP address then saves that to a text document or enters it into the prompt? I want to be able to plug my flash drive into a computer, run said batch file and either use that IP address or save it.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? If you have Windows 7 or Vista it opens up a lot more capabilities for batch files, otherwise if you're on XP and can't use a scripting language, you're basically SOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FULL code

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.


FOR /F "TOKENS=2* DELIMS=:" %%A IN ('IPCONFIG ^| FIND "IPv4"') DO FOR %%B IN (%%A) DO SET IPADDR=%%B
ECHO %IPADDR% > file.txt



:End
```

The previous code will store your local ip into file.txt

Comment: Sadly, I'd have to answer that question in a programming language. In c++ I could give you a simple little program, but batch, I'm not sure, I'll do a little bit of googling for ya.

Comment: Are you opposed to a programmatic solution?

Comment: I'd like to keep it in batch if that's what you mean.

Comment: Alright, well I see some things you can do, you can look into the FIND batch command. 
http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/batch-file-finding-the-ip-address/13900.html
otherwise I would really recommend a program for this, it would take seconds in c++, if you want one you can send me an email ultifinitus@gmail.com

Comment: I'm assuming you want the local IP right?

Comment: Correct. I want to put this as a function in a larger file, so C++ would not work, but that you. If Python was as good at interacting with the computer, I'd've been done hours ago.

Comment: 'IPCONFIG |FIND "IPv4 Address'
Thanks!

Comment: Well you could simply have the c++ program start your batch file once it's done getting the IP, you could even store the batch file in the program if you wanted so you only have one file. Or you could go the other way, have your batch file run a c++ program which could save a new text file with the IP and then read in that file to do what you want.

Is that find function what you're looking for?

Comment: Wait, okay, that gives me:
'   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.20'
How do I get rid of the "   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ?"

Comment: I wish I knew more batch, I'll see what I can find.  
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverGP/thread/5d719a94-28fe-4781-80e3-705715189f51     &&      
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/getip_bat.txt

Comment: You rock man. Is there a friend feature on this site?

Comment: Haha no, but you can email me, and I'll give you a hand when I can.

Comment: It was the delims command, if you looked at the last link, down at the bottom that should be what you need =)
Hope I helped!

Comment: Yeah I see the Delims part, but how is that used? Like, what do I put in to get it to delete what I want?

Comment: If I'm right, a delimiter will stop reading once we get to that point. (that's what the term means in c++) I'm guessing you should then continue reading the line after : and store that in your text file.

Comment: Haha, lets see if I can whip up some batch (haven't done a whit for at least 2 years) give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

Just run the follow

IpConfig >> C:\myip.txt

Comment: The guy above you is winning. Step up your game!