# Is there a way to change the Subnet Mask using NETSH without changing the IP Address?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd, netsh

Our company is planning on switching to a new subnet in the near future to make more room on the network. I thought that the transition might go smoother if we had a batch file that everyone could run to change the subnet for them.

My code thus far looks like this:

```
set maskvar=255.255.255.0
ECHO Setting IP Address and Subnet Mask
netsh interface ip set address local static mask=%maskvar%
```

This doesn't work because it wants a value for the address as well, which would look something like this.

```
netsh interface ip set address local static addr=%addrvar% mask=%maskvar%
```

I would like to keep the address that is already on the machine. Can I pull it from an already existing variable? Is there a better way to do this?

Any useful input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use fixed addresses instead of DHCP in a business environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get IP address from IPConfig, use later in code, or save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414800/get-ip-address-from-ipconfig-use-later-in-code-or-save)

Answer (score 0):

Why not pull the ip address from ipconfig, set it as a variable and then assign it in netsh?

Comment: Your post got me looking and I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414800/get-ip-address-from-ipconfig-use-later-in-code-or-save. I was able to use it to complete the project. Thanks for your input!.